# Is there an Mac OX application for searching the Java API?

Tags: java, api, macos

Is there an application like [Ingredients](http://fileability.net/ingredients/) which lets your browse the Coco API but for Java on OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an application called **Dash** which I have been using it for years now. It is available in the Mac App Store (MAS) here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

**Local:**

Since you are using OSX if you have the Javadoc downloaded and expanded locally you can use Spotlight.

**Online:**

Here is a neat [trick](http://blog.emptyway.com/2007/04/12/quick-search-for-javadocs-in-firefox/) if you use FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to just browse the default javadoc-based HTML pages.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/